# How do I convert a text file to the EPUB format?

Tags: conversion, epub

I have a bunch of book length text files I'd really like to read on my [EPUB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPUB) reader (as it happens FBReaderJ). What would be the best route to convert them?

I have access to Mac OS X and Linux (Ubuntu). Probably happiest with a command line, but would setting for a GUI for batch conversion.

My criteria for success are really based upon the shortfalls I have found with **Calibre**

- must do the whole book
- at least a guess of what the title/author may be. Minimum the source filename for the title.
- hygienic with files it uses - tidies up after itself (this is less important)
- doesn't try to be an all-in-one library manager (again, less important).
- is lenient in parsing special characters (e.g. < and & characters).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the Mac OS X and Windows, I have had success with [Stanza for Desktop](http://www.lexcycle.com/stanza).

This supports a good range of export formats.

More importantly, it copes very well with

- detecting chapters in large text files.
- unicode, including "significant" characters like < and &.

Answer (score 14):

Happened upon this thread many moons later.

Just liked to point out there is a command line tool Calibre uses to convert. It's called (surprise, surprise) ebook-convert. See 'ebook-convert -h' or 'ebook-convert dummy.html .epub -h' to see conversion options for converting html to epub.

Haven't explored it though. I am most curious about --list-recipes (and if it works), it looks as somethings interesting.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/AaronO/9962667

Found this gist detailing how to get it to work using Brew. It seems a little funny that it's not available for install without Calibre.

Comment: Here's how to install it on macOS:
`brew cask install calibre`.
And then use:
`ebook-convert path/to/input_file.input_format path/to/output_file.epub`.
You can find full documentation here: https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/generated/en/ebook-convert.html

Answer (score 10):

I'd say, [**Calibre**](http://calibre.kovidgoyal.net/) is for you. It works on **Linux, Mac OS X**, and Windows.

> Input Formats: CBZ, CBR, CBC, EPUB,
>   FB2, HTML, LIT, MOBI, ODT, PDF, PRC**,
>   PDB, PML, RB, RTF, TXT
>
> Output Formats: **EPUB**, FB2, OEB, LIT,
>   LRF, MOBI, PDB, PML, RB, PDF, TXT

Comment: Thanks. My criteria were based upon the shortfalls of Calibre.

Comment: ahh, didn't know that ... but when it comes to EPUB, there isn't really much out there except Calibre, even the gurus in an ebook forum where i'm a member don't have other solutions for this format. :(

Comment: I'd point your gurus here! Would love to hear what they have to say (I posted an answer, btw).

Answer (score 2):

There are online tools to convert to epub files.

Example of such a website [here](http://www.web-books.com/Publishing/Word2EPUB.htm).

Comment: Thanks. This worked, although I did need to do some curation on the file. Not yet suitable for batch importing.

Comment: This one supports more sensible input formats, and is quicker: http://www.2epub.com

Answer (score 1):

If you have a MacOS X 10.6 machine, try this:

http://padilicious.com/epub/index.html

It relies on Automator

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try ODFToEPub. This is an OpenOffice extension that lets you export a document to ePub.

http://www.pincette.biz/odftoepub/

Answer (score 0):

Best way to convert to epub is with Calibre, it's free and really easy to do. I just had to do this with a bunch of documents for our sales team to take into the field with the iPad. Here's the guide I used:

http://osxdaily.com/2010/08/12/convert-to-epub/

Free download, quick conversions, doesn't get much better.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's been a while, so FWIW, FBReader now has very decent support for reading pure .txt files.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays libreoffice natively exports to epub. It's not perfect ([e.g. Table Of Contents only take Heading1 into account](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/toc-of-a-document-exported-to-epub/62467)), but I find libreoffice/openoffice the most easiest way to produce a good enough ePub. If you want to format plain texts I recommend the libreoffice plugin [alternative searching](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/en/extensions/show/alternative-dialog-find-replace-for-writer).